# macro_rules!() error: Fix for "the usage of `my_macro!` is likely invalid in impl item context"?

Tags: rust

[Playground link](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=55265c35ebbfe604a6c7ea79b154cc69)

I have several different structs grouped together in an enum:

```rust
pub enum Ty {
    A(AStruct),
    B(BStruct)
}

pub struct AStruct {
    base: BaseStruct
}

impl AStruct {
    base_struct_passthrough_impls!();

    pub fn new(x: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            base: BaseStruct::new(x)
        }
    }
}

pub struct BStruct {
    base: BaseStruct
}

impl BStruct {
    base_struct_passthrough_impls!();

    pub fn new(x: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
           base: BaseStruct::new(x)
        }
    }
}
```

All of these types will share a base struct that is common to them all.  This base struct will have a lot of methods that I don't want to duplicate for each supertype.

```rust
pub struct BaseStruct {
    x: i32
}

impl BaseStruct {
    pub fn new(x: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            x
        }
    }
    
    pub fn get_x(&self) -> i32 {
        self.x
    }
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! base_struct_passthrough_impls {
    () => {
        pub fn get_x(&self) -> i32 {
            self.base.get_x()
        };
    }
}
```

However, trying to use this code results in the following error:

```
error: macro expansion ignores token `;` and any following
  --> src/main.rs:37:10
   |
37 |         };
   |          ^
...
46 |     base_struct_passthrough_impls!();
   |     --------------------------------- caused by the macro expansion here
   |
   = note: the usage of `base_struct_passthrough_impls!` is likely invalid in impl item context
```

It seems like `macro_rules!()` is not usable in the impl item context.  Is this correct, and if so is there anyway around this restriction?  Would a proc macro work here, or would doing something like [this](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/4621#issuecomment-17173745) work better?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The issue isn't the macro usage, but the definition. You included a trailing semicolon after the function definition created by the macro, which is what causes the error. If you remove it, everything works fine - here's the code:

```
fn main() {
    let types = vec![Ty::A(AStruct::new(32)), Ty::B(BStruct::new(64))];
    types.iter().for_each(|item| {
        dbg!(match item {
            Ty::A(a_struct) => a_struct.get_x(),
            Ty::B(b_struct) => b_struct.get_x(),
        });
    })
}

pub enum Ty {
    A(AStruct),
    B(BStruct)
}

pub struct BaseStruct {
    x: i32
}

impl BaseStruct {
    pub fn new(x: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            x
        }
    }
    
    pub fn get_x(&self) -> i32 {
        self.x
    }
}

#[macro_export]
macro_rules! base_struct_passthrough_impls {
    () => {
        pub fn get_x(&self) -> i32 {
            self.base.get_x()
        } // there was an illegal semicolon here
    }
}

pub struct AStruct {
    base: BaseStruct
}

impl AStruct {
    base_struct_passthrough_impls!();

    pub fn new(x: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            base: BaseStruct::new(x)
        }
    }
}

pub struct BStruct {
    base: BaseStruct
}

impl BStruct {
    base_struct_passthrough_impls!();

    pub fn new(x: i32) -> Self {
        Self {
            base: BaseStruct::new(x)
        }
    }
}
```